# Can ttk safely be used with mttkinter?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to use [mttkinter](https://github.com/RedFantom/mtTkinter/wiki) and unfortunately I must use Python 2.7.

Suprisingly, I cannot find any information on whether `ttk` widgets become thread safe when using `mttkinter`.

Do I just have to issue

```
from mttkinter import mtTkinter as tk
import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
# --- use tk and ttk as usual ---
```

or possibly alternatively

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import mttkinter

root = tk.Tk()
# --- use tk and ttk as usual --
```

and everything will work as expected? Is there a preferred version of doing the imports?

The [wiki](https://github.com/RedFantom/mtTkinter/wiki) on github states

> As the mtTkinter module modifies Tkinter in memory, there is no need to change anything else in your program. Just import it once somewhere in your program, and everything should work smoothly.

However, this says nothing about `ttk`. Can anybody give me confirmation that using `ttk` is fine?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what will happen?

Comment: @BryanOakley I just want to be sure. If I can't observe my GUI randomly crashing that's not proof it's thread safe.